# NHibernate QueryOver: Variable 'line' of type 'SomeTable' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Tags: vb.net, nhibernate, queryover

I'm working with legacy data, which often brings me one information splited in multiple columns. I'm trying to reproduce the following SQL query...

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE concat(DescriptionPart1,DescriptionPart2) LIKE 'TEST'
```

...using NHibernate QueryOver. So:

```
Dim myQuery = Me.Session.QueryOver(Of SomeTable).WhereRestrictionOn( _
    Function(line As SomeTable) line.DescriptionPart1 & line.DescriptionPart2) _
    .IsLike("TEST")
```

This own statement will run into the following exception:

```
Variable 'line' of type 'SomeTable' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined
```

Any directions? I'm trying to avoid magic strings, but I'm always giving up to it (as using HQL the concatenation expression + like function works like a charm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, I solved this issue using `Linq`.

The main point of my question (my fault, I haven't mentioned that) was the possibility to reuse code from a base class, so I wanted to extract the Description expression of a given table to use it for multiple purposes. The final idea is implemented as below:

```
Public MustInherit Class DefaultBusinessLogic(Of Poco)

  Public Overridable ReadOnly Property DescriptionExpression as Expression(Of Func(Of Poco, String))
    Get
       Return Nothing
    End Get
  End Property

  Public Function SearchByDescription(searchArgument as String) as IEnumerable(Of Poco)
     Dim nhSession as ISession = SessionManager.GetSession()

     Dim query = nhSession.Query(Of Poco)

     If Not String.IsNullOrWhitespace(searchArgument) AndAlso
        Me.DescriptionExpression IsNot Nothing Then

        searchArgument = "%" & searchArgument & "%"        

        Dim isLikeMi = ReflectionHelper.GetMethod(Sub() LinqHelpers.IsLike(Nothing, Nothing)) '* See (1)
        Dim isLikeExpression = Expression.Call(isLikeMi, Me.DescriptionExpression.Body, Expression.Constant(searchArgument))
        Dim whereExpression = Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of Poco, Boolean))(isLikeExpression, Me.DescriptionExpression.Parameters)
        query = query.Where(whereExpression)
     End If

     Return query.ToList()
  End Function

  Public Function GetDescription(pocoRecord as Poco) as String
     If Me.DescriptionExpression Is Nothing Then Return String.Empty

     Return Me.DescriptionExpression.Compile().Invoke(pocoRecord)
  End Function

End Class
```

---

```
Public Class SomeTableBusinessLogic
   Inherits DefaultBusinessLogic(Of SomeTable)

   Public Overrides ReadOnly Property DescriptionExpression as Expression(Of Func(Of Poco, String))
    Get
       Return Function (row as SomeTable) row.DescriptionPart1 & row.DescriptionPart2
    End Get
  End Property

End Class
```

---

```
Public Class SomeTable

   Public Overridable Property Id as Integer
   Public Overridable DescriptionPart1 as String
   Public Overridable DescriptionPart2 as String

End Class
```

---

- (1) The 'IsLike' method was implemented as a NHibernate Linq extension. [Extracted from here](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com.br/2010/07/nhibernate-linq-provider-extension.html).

Answer (score 1):

a little bit verbose but it works

```
var results = session.QueryOver<SomeTable>()
    .Where(Restrictions.Like(
        Projections.SqlFunction("concat", NHibernateUtil.String, Projections.Property<SomeTable>(x => x.DescriptionPart1), Projections.Property<SomeTable>(x => x.DescriptionPart2)),
        "TEST",
        MatchMode.Anywhere))
    .List();
```